Datagridview to text file, possible to place text in front of each specific column?
I am working on a project to where a datagridview is populated by text boxes. This information contains Name, DOB, Phone number, address, etc. I am then writing the data to a text file.
I am currently using this code:
ReportWriter.WriteLine("")

For Each currentrow As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
For Each currentcolumn As DataGridViewCell In currentrow.Cells
    ReportWriter.Write(currentcolumn.Value & " ")
Next
ReportWriter.WriteLine()
Next

From I get a readout in the format of:
Fred 1/1/1111 1231231234 1234 lane'

Is there any way I can specify text to put in front of each column readout such as "Name:"?
Example:
Name: fred DOB: 1/1/1111 Phone: 1231234567 
Address: 1234 lane


Like so:
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Windows.Forms

'''''''''''''''''

ReportWriter.WriteLine()

Dim cols As List(Of DataGridViewColumn) = Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn).ToList()

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
    For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
        Dim col As DataGridViewColumn = cols(cell.ColumnIndex)
    
        ReportWriter.Write(col.Name)
        ReportWriter.Write(": """)
        ReportWriter.Write(Replace(cell.Value, vbCrLf, "⏎")) ' Replacing line-breaks in the value with the "⏎" symbol.
        ReportWriter.Write(""", ")

    Next

    ReportWriter.WriteLine()

Next

BTW, don't use the & string-concatenation operator when you're using a TextWriter (which is what I assume ReportWriter is): instead it's much more efficient to just write out each concatenated part via .Write.
Also, I added encloding (and escaped) quotes " and field-separators: ,.
So you'll get output like:
Name: "fred", DOB: "1/1/1111", Phone: "1231234567", Address: "1234 lane"

BTW, despite similarity, this is not actually JSON.

for the col.name I am getting "Name is not a member of "DataGridViewCell" is this where I should specify the column? If so on which line do I add the next column. I am sorry I am trying to wrap my head around this.

@R3gulate108 I've updated my answer, thank you for pointing out the error.

You could write [Cell].OwningColumn.HeaderText (the Column's Name is probably not meaningful here, or even null, depending on how the Columns have been added to the grid). No need for the Columns collection

col.Value is throwing the error "is not a member of "DataGridViewColumn"   . I have attempted to use tostring and equals with no success. I have tried to specify the value in Me.DataGridView1 however I just get a repeating value of the data in the very first column. Attempting to work around this.

@R3gulate108 It's just a typo, it's cell.Value of course, not col.Value (you should also know whether that value can be null and treat it as such)

@Jimi Thank you so much. I am trying my best to understand this and still have some learning to do. Thank you for your help.
